# How to display current scope in intellisense?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, intellisense

Is it possible to display only the current class's methods / objects when displaying intellisense (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>)?

I have simple form like this:

```
public partial class TestForm : Form
{
    public TestForm() { InitializeComponent(); }

    private string jobName = "x";

    public int JobId = 0;

    public void DoJob() { }

    private void TestForm_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /*
            When hiting ctrl+space show me only: 
                Dispose(bool)
                DoJob()
                InitializeComponent()
                TestForm()
                TestForm_Loaded(object, System.EventArgs)
                components
                JobId
                jobName
        */
    }
}
```

Comment: What about starting off with `this.`?

Comment: Fully acceptable answer:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you need to access the class' context. You can do that with the `this` keyword in C#, so type `this.` to get the IntelliSense you want. Note it will also display inherited members.

I typically use it to browse the current class if I don't know it too well yet, though I don't use the `this` keyword itself unless necessary, so I delete it afterwards again.